# How could Euro bonds serve as a "safe haven" asset in the long run?

Tags: macroeconomics, bonds, euro-area

The German Bund has been the major safe-haven asset in the Eurozone despite the advent of the Euro. However, I noticed that there is mounting anticipation around a potential 750 billion worth of Euro issuance in coordination with the recovery fund.

The market consensus is that this is a positive for Euro bonds, but I still find the situation a bit perplexing. The commission has had years to promote the Euro (if they agreed that's what they wanted to do), but it's only now, faced with a pandemic, that significant issuance is undertaken. If it takes something as colossal as a pandemic for a meaningful increase in the volume of the Euro bond market, that's not so reassuring for the future of the asset class.

### Question

What evidence is available to suggest that the Euro bond is on a more widespread adoption trajectory in terms of being a safe-haven asset class (and not just a fluke of massive fiscal stimulus from the occasional black swan)?